# Calculate the percentual difference based on years and category

Tags: r

I have the following problem:
I have a data.frame with two factor variables and one numeric variable. One factor variable is year and the other factor variable is a category. The variable year has for each of the two categories the same three years.

```
set.seed(100)    
df <- data.frame(year=c(2000, 2002, 2004),cat=rep(1:2,3), val=round(rnorm(6,5,3)*100,2))

  year cat    val
1 2000   1 349.34
2 2002   2 539.46
3 2004   1 476.32
4 2000   2 766.04
5 2002   1 535.09
6 2004   2 595.59
```

I would like to calculate the percentual difference between the years based on the year 2000 for each category.
two new variables should be added with the following values (based on this example):

```
pd         diff
100        0
70,43      -29,57
136,35     +36,35
100        0
153,17     +53,17
77,75      -22,25
```

I tried the aggregate() function with the diff() function but got no result.
I really would appreciate your help.
Thanks ahead and merry xmas!

Comment: Are you okay with using packages? If so `dplyr` would be a good option with its `group_by` function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a dplyr solution. You need to sort the data.frame by category and year to make use of `dplyr::first()`, so my output slightly differs from yours.

```
set.seed(100)    
df <- data.frame(year=c(2000, 2002, 2004),cat=rep(1:2,3), val=round(rnorm(6,5,3)*100,2))

library(dplyr)
arrange(df,cat,year) %>% 
  group_by(cat) %>% 
  mutate(pd=val/first(val)*100,
         diff=pd - first(pd))

Source: local data frame [6 x 5]
Groups: cat [2]

   year   cat    val        pd      diff
  (dbl) (int)  (dbl)     (dbl)     (dbl)
1  2000     1 349.34 100.00000   0.00000
2  2002     1 535.09 153.17170  53.17170
3  2004     1 476.32 136.34854  36.34854
4  2000     2 766.04 100.00000   0.00000
5  2002     2 539.46  70.42191 -29.57809
6  2004     2 595.59  77.74920 -22.25080
```